# CakePHP Forgot Password / Ticket component help

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the following tutorial to build a password reset form: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/eimermusic/2007/10/23/ticket-component-resetting-user-passwords

However when I submit the form I get the following error: `Fatal error: Class 'Ticket' not found in /Users/cameron/Sites/thehive/app/controllers/components/tickets.php on line 60`

And Line 60 is this: `$ticketObj = new Ticket();`

Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it thanks?

Comment: Cameron try to give more code, please.

Comment: PHP clearly says __Class 'ticket' not found__ !

Comment: But how do I fix the problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models are not automatically available in components. One possible way to import your model class is:

```
App::import('Model','Ticket');
```

Comment: Where do I put this? At the top of the component?

Comment: Yes, you can either put it at the top or just above the line where you instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just forgot to create the Ticket model class:

```
<?php
class Ticket extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Ticket';    
}
?>
```

Just put this in a file "ticket.php" within your /app/model directory.

Comment: You included the component in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Hey... it would make sense if you post your Ticket model class here. Looking back at the tutorial, I don't understand why the duplicates

```
<?php //why duplicate
<?php //why duplicate
class Ticket extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Ticket';    
}
?> //why duplicate
?> //why duplicate
```

. I am not sure if that would cause problem as I have never tried it before. If you copy the code as is, that might be the issue. I am not sure....

Comment: Yeh I know NOT to duplicated the PHP tags (must be an error with their CMS)